# Is it possible to use byte buffer as DataSource of NDK AMediaExtractor?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, audio-streaming, mediaextractor

There is [native extension](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/ndk_media_extractor_8h.html) for `MediaExtractor` API.
But in oppose to JAVA MediaExtractor there is only two functions to set `DataSource`:

- [AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(AMediaExtractor *, const char * location)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/ndk_media_extractor_8h.html#a69c6d35eecd3b62dced9acd641f46bb5)
- [AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(AMediaExtractor *, int fd, off64_t offset, off64_t length)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/ndk_media_extractor_8h.html#aa47a652eb0c42ebc092f40f26b30117b)

I need to read data from byte buffer instead of file. So I can not use both of these functions to set `DataSource`. Because, as far as I understand, `FileDescriptor` (fd) - is kinda link to physical asset on the disk.

Please advise

Comment: who creates that buffer? where do you get your byte data from? what does streaming have to do with it?

Comment: The data in the buffer should appear from `HLS`. And I am looking for way to: 1. read data from HTTP Live Stream; 2. feed the data to `MediaExtractor`

Comment: so you have data producer living in some background thread, right? in this case use [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) function

Comment: wow! with `pipe` it seems like `FD` can be used not only for "physical" objects

Comment: sure it can, and for java part, see `ParcelFileDescriptor` docs and `create*` and `from*` methods

Comment: нет проблем, пожалуйста

Comment: @pskink, no, this is not appropriate due to the way of data transfer should be originated by `FileOutputStream::write()` -- by *writing* to the pipe. But I don't know exactly how much data `AMediaExtractor` needs (for example, to make initial configuration, to extract ContentType, SampleRate, etc). Is it possible to avoid necessity of "writing"? - to make pipe's data be always available on-demand